# pagination handling in Adobe Flex 4

Tags: flex4, adobe

Im using adobe flex as a UI and Spring as middle tier. now i have to retreive search results and it gets me around 2000 records and i would like to paginate them for the user.can anyone please let me know if there is pagination in flex to help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

yeap this is the link, i improved the code there so it should work:

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_pagination_in_flex-9263.html